# How can I export all item IDs, metadata and names? [FTB 1.4.7 Mindcrack]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have used NEIs dump thing but that does not give meta data and the names are average at best. How can I access the item id, meta data and proper name (that you get by hovering over the item in NEI)?

I have seen a mod that does this for 1.5 but not for 1.4.7

I want this data for a table for use in my interactive sorter program

Comment: the duplicated question only contains an answer for 1.5, not 1.4.7 as OP asked

Comment: I've recompiled the solution from the other answer to work for 1.4.7, no changes needed: [ItemDumper for 1.4.7](http://www.mediafire.com/download/rq91496leyp5nzp/ItemDumperv1.4.7.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley you cannot do this at the moment because NEI looks into the game Runtime itself to get that information. It does not support exporting the info.

Using the dump will only give you the game ID for it, when minecraft itself orders items based upon their ID's from mods.

Have you tried going to each mod page and seeing if the data is available that way?

Personally i just spent a couple hours noting the Meta info for all my plugins, because i couldn't find a way to do this either.